# Extracting part of string from two columns at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, string

I would like to extract numbers from two columns at once because I have the situation you see below.

[image]

```
regexp_substr(regexp_substr("Address L1", '(\\d*) ')("Address L2"), '(\\d*)')
```

I tried the code above but it didn't work. How can I use the `regexp_substr` for two columns at once?

Comment: I suppose you could check first, where the number is situated at. I'd use a `CASE WHEN` statement, so you can take features w/o numbers into account.

Comment: try this: `coalesce(regexp_substr( "Address_L1" ,'(^\\d+)'),'-')||', '||coalesce(regexp_substr( "Address_L2" ,'(^\\d+)'),'-')`

Comment: So for your second line you want a 7 in a new column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to work on two different fields, the idea is to `concat`enate them:

```
concat(regexp_substr( "Address L2", '(\\d*) ' ),regexp_substr( "Address L1", '(\\d*) '))
```

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: How about if I would like to extract for instance 19A number?